# Image created from html is not placed properly on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas.js to make screenshot from html and jspdf.js to make pdf.
My html is like below

```
<div id="panel-item-all-annotations">
   <div class="panel-body" id="" style="width: 100%;">
         {{--some html with image--}}
   </div>
</div>
<canvas width="800" height="500" style="display: block;"></canvas>
```

I am using the canvas to place the image of div#panel-item-all-annotations by the JS code like below

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#panel-item-all-annotations"), {canvas: canvas}).then(function(canvas) {
        console.log('Drew on the existing canvas');
});
```

But it is not placing image properly on the canvas. It is placing it at very bottom and right of the canvas like below
[image: Improper image place on canvas]

html2canvas.js url: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
jspdf: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's doing that to you. There must be something else going on. Stripping it down to super-simple stuff seems to work. There's an example here:

https://lab-keqpanlmmw.now.sh

Here is the code but it won't run here on StackOverflow.

```js
function go() {
  let input = document.querySelector("#input");
  let output = document.querySelector("#output");
  html2canvas(input, {
    canvas: output
  });
}
```

```css
#input {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 200px;
}

#output {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="input">
  {{--some html with image--}}
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="go()">Go</button>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="output"></canvas>
</div>
```